# R: Combine a list to a data frame

Tags: arrays, r, list, dataframe

I have a array of names and a function that returns a data frame. I want to combine this array and data frame. For e.g.:

```
>mynames<-c("a", "b", "c")
>df1 <- data.frame(val0=c("d", "e"),val1=4:5)
>df2 <- data.frame(val1=c("e", "f"),val2=5:6)
>df3 <- data.frame(val2=c("f", "g"),val3=6:7)
```

What I want is a data frame that joins this array with data frame. df1 corresponds to "a", df2 corresponds to "b" and so on. So, the final data frame looks like this:

```
Names Var    Val
a     d      4
a     e      5
b     e      5
b     f      6
c     f      6
c     g      7
```

Can someone help me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: You say that df1 corresponds to "a" but how is R supposed to know this?

Comment: @Dason Actually I am iterating over the a data.frame, df(say) and calling a function for each row of the data frame. This function in turn is returning the data frame for each row. So, mynames is the first column of `df` and `df1, df1, df3` are the results for each row (3 in this example) of df. Since the entire code is very big, I kind of generated a example case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers this particular question, but I'm not sure how much help it will be for your actual problem:

```
myList <- list(df1, df2, df3)
do.call(rbind, 
        lapply(seq_along(mynames), function(x) 
          cbind(Names = mynames[x], setNames(myList[[x]], 
                                             c("Var", "Val")))))
#   Names Var Val
# 1     a   d   4
# 2     a   e   5
# 3     b   e   5
# 4     b   f   6
# 5     c   f   6
# 6     c   g   7
```

Here, we create a list of your `data.frame`s, and in our `lapply` call, we add in the new "Names" column and rename the existing columns so that we can use `rbind` to put them all together.